# How to slide SlidingDrawer left to right

Tags: android

I want to slide SlidingDrawer from left to right, I have an option: I can define  android:rotation = 90 in SlidingDrawer tag in xml file, but rotation tag works with Android 3.0

So i m tired to slide this from left to right, Is there any one who helps Me for this?

[image]

[image]

like this, Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use this code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/logo11"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.sliding.TransparentPanel
    android:id="@+id/popup_window"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="1px"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/check1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Satellite View" />
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/check2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Street View" />
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/check3"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Traffic" />
    </com.sliding.TransparentPanel>
    <Button android:id="@+id/show_popup_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/slid4_n"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have got ClassNotFoundException after usig this from this link: http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-sliding-drawer/

Answer (score 0):

check out this nice sample:

http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/03/29/widget-slidingdrawer-top-to-bottom/

make it left to right, and use the layout you wish to use.

about the size of the view, set it to the MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer width .